# Finding Inverse in modulus m

Tags: algebra-precalculus, modular-arithmetic, inverse

I've been learning the Euclidean algorithm and came across this simple problem.

$101^{-1} (mod 203)$

So I attempted it as such:

$203 = 101(2) + 1$

So we got a gcd of 1, we can stop and do:

$1 = 203 - 101(2)$

And since it's mod 203, we have 101(2)

So shouldn't the answer be $2$?
My textbook says it's $201$, 
help would be much appreciated, as this is confusing as ever.

Thanks.

Comment: It's $\color{red}{\boldsymbol{-}}2$, which is congruent to $201$\mod 203$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observe that

$$2\cdot101=202=-1\pmod{203}\implies (101)^{-1}=-2=201\pmod{203}$$

Or using the EA:

$$203=2\cdot101+1\implies1\cdot203+\color{red}{(-2)}\cdot101=1\implies $$

$$\implies101^{-1}=-2\pmod{203}=201\pmod{203}$$

Comment: Is this the Euclidian algorithm, I'm not sure exactly what you're doing?

Comment: Not needed as the value is pretty close to half the modulo, so just follow what is written there.

Answer (score 0):

Since $2\cdot101+1\equiv0\pmod{203}$, we have
$$
2\cdot101\equiv-1\pmod{203}
$$
Multiplying by $-1$ gives
$$
-2\cdot101\equiv1\pmod{203}
$$
But $-2\equiv201\pmod{203}$. Therefore,
$$
201\cdot101\equiv1\pmod{203}
$$
and this is exactly what $201\equiv101^{-1}\pmod{203}$ means.

Comment: Id really like to stick to the euclidean algorithm as I wouldn't be able to come up with this of the top of my head

Comment: Well, you had $203\color{#C00000}{-2\cdot101}=1$ which means that $-2\cdot101\equiv1\pmod{203}$, so $-2$ is $101^{-1}$ modulo $203$. Euclid's Algorithm has already been used to get the first equation.